# I'm having trouble using the event.preventDefault(); for an ahref on my DOM

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, events, preventdefault

I'm having trouble using the `event.preventDefault();` for an `ahref` on my DOM.

How do you prevent the url from posting a nofollow delete, as specified by the HTML using JQuery?

```
<td class="trash_can">
<a rel="nofollow" data-remote="true" data-method="delete" data-confirm="Are you sure you want to delete Greek Theater at U.C. Berkeley?" href="/promotions/2/places/46">
<img id="trash_can" src="http://test.dev/images/trash.png?1305741883" alt="Trash">
```

The following code should subvert the HTML but the HTML posts a delete action, prior to giving a "are you sure" warning. nothing is not working:

```
  $(function(){
  $('.trash_can a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('Clicked Delete');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible that instead of just `event.preventDefault()`, you need to do `return false` also or instead.  preventDefault() prevents the default action, but the event still bubbles up, possibly to the next handler, which could be the rails handler that Fredrik pointed out:

```
 $(rails.linkClickSelector).live('click.rails', function(e) {
    var link = $(this);
    if (!rails.allowAction(link)) return rails.stopEverything(e);

    if (link.data('remote') !== undefined) {
      rails.handleRemote(link);
      return false;
    } else if (link.data('method')) {
      rails.handleMethod(link);
      return false;
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 6):

Are you using rails? Looks like it.

The reason `event.preventDefault()` doesn't work is because the magic is done elsewhere. 
Rails comes with some helpers that creates event handlers for all the "delete" actions generated by Rails. So in your case I think that you need to find out how to override the helpers or just create a custom event handler for that specific delete action.

This is the JQuery code that Rails uses:

https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js

Based on this (from the link):

```
linkClickSelector: 'a[data-confirm], a[data-method], a[data-remote]'
```

Your event handler will be the only one executed if you'd remove `data-remote`, `data-method` and `data-confirm` from the link.

So I suggest that you remove them and then just re-create whatever behavior you want in your own click handler.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, but failed to get any good solution after breaking my head for hours. So, based on the suggested answers here, I did something like:

```
function enableLink() {
  jQuery("#link_id").removeClass("disabled");
  jQuery("#link_id").attr("data-remote", true);
}


function disableLink() {
  jQuery("#link_id").addClass("disabled");
  jQuery("#link_id").removeAttr("data-remote");
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(document).on("click", "disabled", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

I accept it's not a good workaround. But, thats what helped me.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but if you are using Rails 5.1+ with the vanilla UJS instead of jQuery one, neither `event.preventDefault()` nor returning `false` from the method stops rails-ujs from handling it. You need to explicitly call [`Rails.stopEverything(event)`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0f70b025839f4df9267de0d5a7fb23d4db1a0c83/actionview/app/assets/javascripts/rails-ujs/utils/event.coffee#L45)

```
$('.trash_can a').click(function(event) {
  Rails.stopEverything(event);
  console.log('Clicked Delete');
});
```