# Ajax no redirect

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a nested resource, `project/:id/keys` and on `.../keys/new` I have a `form_for`, the behaviour of this form was modified in JS and its suppose to do a POST request on submit.

The POST request is working fine, but the problem is that it redirects me to another page, more exactly the form action which is 'projects/:id/keys' with the error that create template was not found.

```
def create
word = word_params[:name]
Word.creates_words word, @project
 respond_to do |format|
   format.html
   format.json {render json: word}
 end
end


$('#new_word').on "submit", (event) ->
  event.preventDefault()
  url = $(this).attr('action')
  data = $('#word_name').val()
  add_words(url, data)

add_words = (url, data_param) ->
  $.ajax
    type: 'POST'
    url: url
    data: word: {name: data_param}
    dataType: 'JSON'
    success: (json) ->
      console.log(json)
```

Comment: Add 'return false' after event.preventDefault() to see if that changes things.

Comment: Have you seen this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296995/im-having-trouble-using-the-event-preventdefault-for-an-ahref-on-my-dom

Comment: Nothing helped, but what I missed to say before, is that console.log is not called.

Comment: console.log() is never called because you're redirecting instead of staying in the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making a manual AJAX request, I advise you to use the `remote: true` parameter of the form_for:

```
<%= form_for ..., remote: true do |f| %>
  # your form
```

Then, in your create action, you can simply do:

```
def create
  # ...
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js {render json: word}
  end
 end
```

You can read more about the remote option [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#form-for)

However, if you still want to submit your data with your own AJAX request, you can just disable your submit button:

```
 <button type='button' id='some_id'>Submit</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, I removed the button and now is working fine.